# c# TCP server accept text and binary

Tags: c#, tcp

I have written a simple TCP server in C#. It is meant to receive commands from clients (and then pass them on for further processing). These commands, and their arguments, are text. (Meaning the client encodes the text commands and the server then decodes them back to text to interpret them.)

Some of these commands take a binary file (e.g. a ZIP file) as parameter.

Now I don't know how to differentiate between text and binary data on the server-side. The server receives only binary data anyway, some of which is meant to be decoded into text, some is not. How do I determine which is which?

I suppose I would have to define some sort of protocol. However, I don't really know how to go about that.

Thank you in advance for any advice and tips!

Chris.

Comment: If you don't mind a 33% overhead on your file size, you could encode your binary files as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: You need an application layer along with the TCP transportation layer.  The Client Sends commands and the server processes the commands.  So you can add a one byte command in front of each message.  The server removes the one byte and then process the rest of the message.  Since you are sending binary I would also add a byte count to each message to server know where the data actually ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a protocol. TCP is just a bare-bones stream of bytes, anything more than that requires an application protocol (as you've implicitly done when interpreting that stream of bytes as individual text messages).

Mixing text and binary data is always tricky. For one, text is *hideously* complicated - most application protocols work around this by assuming ASCII for any significant text. However, if you stick to ASCII, a lot of things get much easier.

Let's assume you send commands separated by `\r`. To parse a command, you need to read up to the first `\r`, and then parse the text command you received. Now when you know what the command *is*, you can deal with the data that follows - so you can have a command like `SENDFILE`, which has an argument that is the length of the file, so the server knows that after it reads the command itself, it should interpret the next `length` of bytes as the file being sent.

There's many subtleties to designing protocols, and TCP itself is not very easy to do right. I'd highly recommend using a higher-level communication protocol, like WCF for example. If you *must* use raw TCP, you have a lot of studying in front of you, and a lot of trial and error :)

Comment: To supplement this answer, have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I finally went for all binary, with length-prefixing for the transmitted message, as well as for the individual data items inside of it. Once I know what command has been transmitted, I know what type of arguments to expect and convert/decode them appropriately.